# JavaFX: Show a Dialog window when a user clicks the X button?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a basic JavaFX program and I'm trying to add functionality where if the user clicks the window's X button, a Dialog button appears. How would I hook into the X button?

Comment: please do some research before asking ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `EventHandler` to the stage's close request:

```java
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent e) {
        // SHOW A DIALOG HERE
        Platform.exit();
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```